# IMU with robot_localization

Tags: ros, navigation, ros-kinetic, robot-localization

[image: Rosanswers logo]

Hello,
I want to use XSENS MTi-30-AHRS Imu with robot_localization for enhancing odometry data.
I aligned IMU x , y z frame according to base_link frame.
But Imu gives yaw angle according to magnetic north. How will I fuse this yaw data with odometry data.
How will I use IMU yaw for fuse data with robot_localization??

---

[Originally posted](https://answers.ros.org/question/328947/imu-with-robot_localization/) by [zeynep](https://answers.ros.org/users/28278/zeynep/) on ROS Answers with karma: 47 on 2019-07-19

Post score: 0

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[image: Rosanswers logo]

It sounds like your question boils down to "how can I fuse absolute yaw data from odometry and my IMU, when they don't agree?"

In general, my advice is not to do that, especially when one of the sources is subject to drift. You have two alternatives.

- Try fusing absolute yaw from your IMU, and yaw velocity from your wheel odometry, or vice-versa.
- Turn on `differential` mode for at least one of the sensors (probably wheel odometry).

---

Originally posted by [Tom Moore](https://answers.ros.org/users/3384/tom-moore/) with karma: 13689 on 2019-08-22

This answer was **ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 1

---

#### Original comments

**Comment by [zeynep](https://answers.ros.org/users/28278/zeynep/) on 2019-08-23**:
I implemented as you suggest. Results are satisfactory.
Thank you.